# What does the IcsService process do?

Tags: services

Under running services, I see the **IcsService** or long name **com.android.samsung.IcsService** . What does that process do? I'm debating about removing it.

Note I have a AT&T Samsung Captivate (Galaxy S)

Answer (score 1):

ICS = Internet Connection Sharing.  I believe it's the service that lets a computer connect to the internet through your device over USB.  You can safely remove it if you don't use it.

Comment: How does this compare to wifi tethering provided by one of android's apps?

Comment: I think the apps might rely on this service, but I'm not sure.  You could use Titanium Backup to "freeze" this service, and see whether your app stops working.